# How can I create this particular paper texture by shader nodes?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

[image]
I want to emulate this exact paper texture via shader nodes, I know I can go about with using the image textures but I want multiple variations of this texture, therefore I need a procedural way to do it.

Things that I have tried:

1. Used the waves texture node, created a grid of sorts and tried to emulate the pattern by distorting the grid. Didn't work.
2. Used voronoi texture node, but they offer very little control to get the needed look.

What can I do to make the pattern of this texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a mix between 2 *Noise Texture* nodes, one for big details, one for smaller details, with a *Color > MixRGB* in *Multiply* mode:

[image]

Or a *Noise* and a *Voronoi*:

[image]

If you want to create a more regular grid you can mix 2 *Wave Texture* nodes and rotate one about 45°, perturbate a bit the *Texture Coordinate* with a *Noise Texture*, then at the end mix the result with a *Noise Texture* to add micro details like in the previous solutions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This is wonderful. However, I was wondering whether there is a way to control this noise to make a grid of sorts. I know I am not describing what I want to say perfectly, but if you look at the image I attached, the paper looks like it has been pressed and the press has left marks in an even grid like manner. The noise texture has random marks instead of the ordered grid like pattern of my image.
It'd be amazing to learn a way to achieve this if you got my point. Thank you again!

Comment: @BlenderBeginner Please see my edit, I've given a try with 2 mixed Wave Texture nodes

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me so much time fiddling around!